# TinyMce - Can i set editor height to 40px which have to allow autoresizing

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I have to set the editor height to 40px, please look to this problem, i tried many times. is there any minimum height for tinymce iframe?

Comment: What have you tried, what has been the result, what was wrong with the result. We need more info before we can even attempt to answer this question. A brief look at the docs indicates you can set the max height of TinyMCE using an option in the initialization - `tinymce.init({max_height: 500});` - Have you tried that? What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution to this problem

```
tinymce.init({
                    selector: "textarea",
                    plugins: ["paste autoresize"],
                    icon: false, menubar: false, statusbar: false, toolbar: false, autoresize_bottom_margin: 2, object_resizing: false,
                    paste_as_text: true, force_br_newlines: false, forced_root_block: false, autoresize_min_height: 40, autoresize_max_height: 300})
```

it achieved by setting forced_root_block: false

Answer (score 0):

There's not a minimum. Find in code height and define it like this -> `height : 40`